# Clipping multiple rasters by set distance / extent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, batch

For a current project, I have 72 geo-referenced OS maps in place.

[image: example]

Unfortunately, all maps have a narrow border with the grid squares / scales on (see image), which obscures the sides of the adjacent maps.

Is there any way to clip this border from all the rasters at once / in bulk, without having to manually clip each raster by extent?

All maps are saved as `.jpgs` with corresponding `TAB`-files.

Comment: You could mitigate the problem by setting white as fully transparent.

Comment: look for questions about GDAL neatline

Comment: Setting the white as transparent has somewhat mitigated it, thanks! It looks a little pixelated around some of the edges but largely clear